# How to send a URL in route parameter?

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I have defined a route like this :

```
$app->map(['GET', 'POST'],'/abc/[{url}]', function ($request, $response, $args) {

    return $response;
})->add(new CustomMiddleware());
```

Its working fine when I pass a url without `http://` but gives me a `404 page not found`-Page with `http://` or `https://`. I have also tried with url encoded string but gives same error :

```
http://localhost/slim/public/index.php/abc/http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com

The requested URL /slim/public/index.php/abc/http://stackoverflow.com was not found on this server.
```

I am using Slim Version 3.1.

Comment: When my answer could help you,please mark it as correct one.

Comment: @jmattheis your answer is good but didn't served my problem. Please go through the question how i want to pass the argument..?? am already aware about the way you suggested but i want to do it my way.. anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes look at my answer, why its not possible to pass it with not encoded ``/``, then how it is possible with encoded ``/``. I dont know what you want now.

Answer (score 5):

**Using an url inside the url**

When you adding the url with Slashes then the route do not get execute cause then there is additional path after the url which is not definied inside the route:

E.g. `example.org/abc/test` works fine but `example.org/abc/http://x`
will only work with a route definition like this `/abc/{url}//{other}`.

**Using an encoded url inside the url**

Apache blocks all request with `%5C` for `\` and `%2F` for `/` in the url with a 404 Not Found error this is because of security reasons. So you do not get a 404 from the slim framework but from your webserver. So you'r code never gets executed.

You can enable this by setting [`AllowEncodedSlashes On`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) in you'r `httpd.conf` of apache.

**My Recommendation to fix this**

Add the url as a get parameter there is is valid to have encode slashes without changing the apache config.

Example call `http://localhost/abc?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com`

```
$app->map( ['GET', 'POST'], '/abc', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $getParam = $request->getQueryParams();
    $url= $getParam['url']; // is equal to http://stackoverflow.com
});
```

Comment: I found a life  saver here ^^