# PHP url's GET parameter blocked by apache

Tags: php, apache

I have a problem with apache giving me a "Forbidden" error if the query string contains has the word 'set'. Anything with this word is giving me the Forbidden error for example:

```
site.com/get.php?username=setadams
```

or

```
site.com/get.php?username=adamsset
```

If the url doesn't have the word "set", there are no issues.

Comment: Check your `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` files.

Comment: It's probably a bad pattern in a rewrite rule

Comment: Check this one .https://stackoverflow.com/a/39375297/3335776

Comment: This one is also help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45326140/3335776